# Consistent left-aligning of a numerical list

Tags: css

How do you make sure all the content in a numerical list is left aligned to the same spot? You see how when you go from #9 to #10, the numbering gets an extra digit and pushes the content a little bit to the right? I can live with #99-to-#100 screwing things up, but I'd like to fix this #9-to-#10 issue. Making the numbering go outside makes the content align properly, but then there's no background on the numbering.

[image: numerical list]

```
#file ol {
    line-height: 3em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #999;
}

    #file ol li {
        list-style: decimal inside none;
        padding: 0 0 0 1em;
    }

    #file ol li.alt {
        background: #eee;
    }
```

Comment: Could you add a HTML sample, or preferably make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list style needs to be outside for this to happen.

```
#file ol li {
    list-style: decimal outside none;
    padding: 0 0 0 1em;
}
```

The only other option, to fix your background issues, would be to use another element inside the LI that you place `inline-block` with a predefined width and manually increment or to use a table. If your project does not rely on backwards compatability, please let me know as there may be some CSS3 options.

Comment: I know tables align things neatly, but it wouldn't work for me because I allow people to drag and drop elements in this list. By using an `<ol>`, the numbering updates automatically when items are shuffled around. I'd prefer to not use extra markup to fix the background issue. At this point, HTML would be solely added for styling purposes, which CSS is supposed to do. But if it's the only way then.... I'll do it.

Comment: @David, CSS 3, heh. @JoJo, if you want automatic numbering, you need to use list, outside decimal (I'm actually surprised that works in all browsers). You need to strike a balance on the importance of your design elements and the posibilities of implementation.

Comment: Ahhh...now *that* makes more sense! =D

Comment: There's many solutions to design problems. The best are the ones done with CSS. Moving towards HTML or JS solutions make the code hairier. JS can solve almost any design problem, but it's not ideal.

Comment: @JoJo, I don't know what you expect me to tell you. I don't know your requirements, so I cant provide anything more than the facts. There is a solution using CSS3's :before, nth-*, and numbering properties, but then you lose support for 90% of browsers. I don't think you are going to find a better answer than what I've provided to be 100% compatible with all browsers.

Comment: I guess we all lose because of IE. Sad sad world we live in.