# Overflown ordered list does not increment

Tags: html, css

Why does an ordered list not increment when the list item has hidden overflow? Here's a simplified example. My actual application needs hidden overflow because the list items have floated children.

**HTML**

```
<ol>
    <li>uno</li>
    <li>dos</li>
    <li>tres</li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
ol li {
    list-style: decimal inside none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Output** (Firefox 4)

```
0. uno
0. dos
0. tres
```

**Output** (Internet Explorer 7)

```
1. uno
1. dos
1. tres
```

**Output** (Chrome, Internet Explorer 8)

```
1. uno
2. dos
3. tres
```

**Live example**

http://jsfiddle.net/tokyotech/DCgq3/

Comment: Interesting. This question was asked on Mozilla forums around 7 months ago. Someone there asked the user to ask it here on this site! So looks like a lot of people have this issue and could be a mozilla bug. http://support.mozilla.com/sr-CYRL/questions/743744

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ol {
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;  
    counter-reset: item;
}

ol li {
    list-style: decimal inside none;
    background: pink;
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom: 3px dotted #000;       
    margin-left: 1em;
}

ol li div {
    background: #999;
    width: 20em;
    height: 2em;
    margin: 0.2em;
}


li:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: counter(item);
    counter-increment: item;    
    width: 2em;
    margin-left: -1em;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/DCgq3/62/

Comment: You don't need the `display: list-item`. As soon as you remove the `overflow: hidden` property it starts working in FF. No idea why FF is behaving that way. could be some sort of a bug.

Comment: Each `<li>` needs to expand with a dynamic number of floated children, so I do need overflow on the `<li>`.

Comment: Even if you have floating childs, there is not reason to use overflow on both ul and li. It would help if you post your code on jsfiddle and point out why you need overflow on li. Otherwise the solution i provided is the only solution i see available.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tokyotech/DCgq3/61/ - here's where I need the `<li>` to have overflow. There are an arbitrary number of floated elements in each `<li>`. If the `<li>` didn't have `overflow:hidden`, then the `border-bottom` would not be in the right place. Another issue that arises is that the numbering has now jumped to the right edge in FF4.

Comment: This solution will not fix IE7 because it does not understand `:before`. I also need the background to encompass the numbering. See my old question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225965/consistent-left-aligning-of-a-numerical-list . Thanks for the effort though. Seems like this is a tough question.

Comment: Layout questions aside, the original question is still unsolved for IE7.

Comment: number incrementation and browser support was the question and i gave you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Uh-Oh was expecting the IE7 "burp" but not FF4 :(

IE7 is a haslayout problem, notoriously it cannot number  lists (even has trouble putting a plain bullet sometimes)

why FF4 I don't know, will take a look