# Firefox issue displays zeros when displaying divs as ordered list items?

Tags: css, firefox, html, listitem, html-lists

Have a look at -

http://jsfiddle.net/v23UU/13/

It works in IE and Chrome but not in firefox 4 does anyone know why ? 
I found something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413400/overflown-ordered-list-does-not-increment) but could not figure out how to get it to work ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: Not to say there shouldn't be a way to do this, but is there a reason you can't just use semantic list item tags `<li>` instead of styling your own arbitrary `<div>`?  On that note, I played around with a few things and couldn't get it to work on firefox 5 either... So I'm curious what the issue is, but I think you should just use `<li>`'s the way they were meant to be used.

Comment: Yea..probably going to that..I was just wondering what's going on here.

Comment: Just put a `<ol>` around your list-items and it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that list-item counters are not actually CSS counters in Gecko, mostly.  See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4522 for details.

To get it to work, you need to either use CSS counters or have an actual list element around.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect answer to your question, but a work-around nonetheless.

I spent the better half of a day trying to figure out how to work around this frustratingly old bug (14 years for one bugfix? Seriously Mozilla?). I couldn't figure out a solution that fixed the problem, but eventually I settled on a compromise which is better than nothing.

In the CSS file:

```
    .mylist{
       display: list-item;
       list-style: decimal;
    }

    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
       .mylist {
          list-style: disc;
       }
    }
```

Displays in Opera, IE, Chrome:

```
    1. Item 1
    2. Item 2
```

Displays in Firefox:

```
    * Item 1
    * Item 2
```

This applies the decimal list style to the .mylist class in all browsers except Firefox, which gets the disc list style instead. This is not ideal, as it still doesn't properly order your list in Firefox, but at least it allows the list to properly display in most browsers while turning it into an unordered list in Firefox rather than a list of items starting with "0.".

Jsfiddle doesn't seem to like the "@-moz-document" syntax for whatever reason, but it works in live pages.